# No extrusion, but manual extrusion works. The motor turns but no filaments pushed down

Tags: diy-3d-printer

My printer doesn't have extrusion but when I push it manually it extrudes just fine.

The extruder motor turns but it won't really push the filaments to get extruded.

I am using the same G-code file that was used two years ago and back then it extruded without any issue. But to think it is the problem of hardware. The extruder extrudes well when I tried to prime the filament (I use gel). So I am confused whether this is a problem of extruder hardware or G-code.

[image: Screenshot of G-code]

**Transcribed** G-code from screenshot (may contain errors/differences)

```
; generated by PrusaSlicer 2.3.3+win64 on 2021-12-15 at 16:39:29 UTC

;

; external perimeters extrusion width = 0.15mm 
; perimeters extrusion width = 0.15mm
; infill extrusion width = 0.15mm 
; solid infill extrusion width = 0.15mm
; top infill extrusion width = 0.15mm 
; first layer extrusion width = 0.15mm

M107
;TYPE:Custom
G55
T0
M302 P1
g90
G21 ; set units to millimeters
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
M82 ; use absolute distances for extrusion
G92 E0
; Filament gcode 
;LAYER CHANGE
;Z:0.06
;HEIGHT:0.06
G1 Z0.060 F900.000
G1 X-0.092 Y-0.377
;TYPE:Perimeter
;WIDTH:0.15
G1 X0.116 Y-0.418 E0.00004
G1 X0.328 Y-0.418 E0.00008
G1 X0.536 Y-0.377 E0.00012
G1 X0.731 Y-0.298 E0.00016
G1 X0.906 Y-0.184 E0.00020
G1 X1.053 Y-0.040 E0.00024
G1 X1.169 Y0.128 E0.00027
G1 X1.248 Y0.315 E0.00031
G1 X1.288 Y0.512 E0.00035
G1 X1.288 Y0.712 E0.00309
```

Comment: It is preferable to paste in the actual code instead of a picture of the code. This allows users in the future that do a search can actually find your code.

Comment: This [suggested edit](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16980), whilst an admirable effort and attempt at transcribing the screenshot, is ***not*** exactly the same as the G-code in the screenshot. There may be some differences. It would be ***much better*** if the OP could just paste in the **actual** G-code..

Comment: It seems like your extrusion multiplier might be off.
Apparently you're using a layer height of 0.06 and an extrusion width of 0.15. For your moves (traveling around 1.5 mm diagonally) I would expect 0,0135 mm³ of filament being extruded. However, your extruder only moves 0,00031 mm, which would be 0,00074 mm³ with 1.75mm filament or 0,0019 mm³ with 2.85mm filament - off by factors of 18 or 7 respectively.